# MySQL - select a random entry per group with N total rows

Tags: mysql

I want to be able to select one random row per group for a total of N rows. Example:

simple table schema:

`id shoetype shoename`

each "group" is a `shoetype`, and there are multiple `shoenames` per `shoetype`. I want to be able to select a total of N rows, but only one random `shoename` from each `shoetype`.

---

`SELECT * FROM table GROUP BY shoetype ORDER BY RAND()` does not seem to get a random one from each type but just the first shoetype... i am not sure how to write a query to get a random one from each group?

Answer (score 0):

Here's the best way to achieve this

http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?132,185266,194715

Comment: this doesn't seem to work if you want a random entry per group

Comment: It does if you do a select distinct groupname, (select RAND SUBSELECT) as rand_id, then inner join the rand_id on a record to get the remaining data

Answer (score 0):

select * from (select * from mytable order by rand()) as MT group by shoetype

is my shot at it. This scrambles the table order, then does a normal sort of group by